# Find mean of multiple columns in R

Tags: r

My dataset looks like this:

```
values<-c(9,8,NA,8)
acceptance<-c(8,8,NA,6)
diffusion<-c(9,8,7,NA)
attitudes<-c(7,7,6,NA)
df<-data.frame(values,acceptance,diffusion,attitudes)

values  acceptance  diffusion  attitudes

  9         8          6           8 
  8         8          8           7
  NA        NA         7           6
  8         6          NA          NA
```

I can use the code `mean(df$values, na.rm = T)` to get the mean for each column, but I'd like to create a new variable for the total mean of specific columns (ex: values & acceptance). I could just use the same code for each column I want to include and then figure out the mean that way:

```
mean(df$values, na.rm = T) = 8.333
mean(df$acceptance, na.rm = T) = 7.333
(8.333 + 7.333)/2 = 7.833
df$values_acceptance<-7.833
```

But this would be really inefficient because I have multiple variables I need to include. I'm sure there is a much easier way to do this, but I'm still getting used to R.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: df$values_acceptance <- mean( unlist( df[c(“values”,”acceptance”)] ), na.tm =TRUE) this will get recycled to the number of row in df regardless of whether there any NAs in the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `colMeans` on the selected columns and get the `mean` of it, then assign the output to create new column (no packages are needed)

```
df$values_acceptance<- mean(colMeans(df[c('values', 'acceptance')], na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
> df
  values acceptance diffusion attitudes values_acceptance
1      9          8         9         7          7.833333
2      8          8         8         7          7.833333
3     NA         NA         7         6          7.833333
4      8          6        NA        NA          7.833333
```

---

Or if we need `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(values_acceptance = mean(unlist(across(c(values,
         acceptance), mean, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

-output

```
values acceptance diffusion attitudes values_acceptance
1      9          8         9         7          7.833333
2      8          8         8         7          7.833333
3     NA         NA         7         6          7.833333
4      8          6        NA        NA          7.833333
```

Comment: If you have lots of columns, you can also refer to your columns of interest by index, e.g. `df %>% mutate(values_acceptance_diffusion = mean(unlist(across(c(1:3), mean, na.rm = TRUE))))` or `df %>% mutate(values_acceptance_diffusion = mean(unlist(across(c(1,2,3), mean, na.rm = TRUE))))`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `c()` to combine the columns you want calculate the total mean:

```r
df %>% mutate(new=mean(c(values,acceptance),na.rm = T))
  values acceptance diffusion attitudes      new
1      9          8         9         7 7.833333
2      8          8         8         7 7.833333
3     NA         NA         7         6 7.833333
4      8          6        NA        NA 7.833333
```

Answer (score 0):

You may approach this way

```
df %>%
  select(values, acceptance) %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  summarise(n = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

result is like

```
         n
1 7.833333
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use mapply

```
df2 <- mapply(mean,df,na.rm=T)
```

Which produces

```
   values acceptance  diffusion  attitudes 
  8.333333   7.333333   8.000000   6.666667
```

Or if you want to mean of each column mean you could go

```
mean(mapply(mean,df,na.rm=T))

[1] 7.583333
```

If you need to specify specific columns you can do the following

```
mean(mapply(mean,df[c(1:2)],na.rm=T))

[1] 7.833333
```

and use na.rm twice if one of the columns means will have a NA

```
mean(mapply(mean,df[c(1:2)],na.rm=T),na.rm=T)
```